# Can't access website on local IP address, but loads with public IP

Tags: windows, networking, ip, putty, ruby-on-rails

There is something weird going on since tonight.

I have a raspberry pi running a ruby on rails server. When I run my local IP address on my phone there is no problem, and the website loads normally. But when I try my PC to run the same address, I get a connection timeout. When I run my public address there is no problem, and the site loads.

This same problem goes with PUTTY. Local address doesn't work, but external IP works fine.

I tried to disable my firewall, restart my computer, renewed my IP (ipconfig /release, and /flushdns, before /renew), but this didn't help.

Does anyone had this problem too, or know how to fix it?

Comment: The network is pretty straight forward. Modem(with onboard wifi), switch, computer. All the computers and phones are on the same LAN (192.168.0.x) The server(on a raspberry pi) and my phone are connected trough WIFI. My computer is connected with wire. But it's strange, I restarted my computer and it couldn't connect with putty anymore. I haven't deleted or installed anything in the meantime.

Comment: Can you include the output on `iptables -nvL`. The raspberry Pi and your PC are in the same subnet?

Comment: @JorimStraver Don't use comments to add relevant information to your question. [Edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/1112995/edit) instead.

Comment: @MarkoPolo Yes. One ends on 14 and the other on 16. they are both in the same subnet mask.